# Kubernetes pod cannot access localhost resources, but can use curl [SOLVED]

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, service, localhost, amazon-eks

I deployed an API service developed in node.js on AWS Kubernates.
The API service also exposes a static path to a folder that contains images.
But the service is unable to fetch images from localhost.

The service to get the images, uses the *request* library, and I can't change it, and executes the following function:

```
function(img, url, callback) { 

            var requestOpts = {
                url: url,
                method: 'GET',
                encoding: null,
                gzip:true
            };

            request(requestOpts, function (err, response, body) {
                if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    img.onload = function() {
                        callback(null);
                    };
                    img.onerror = function() {
                        callback(new Error('Could not load marker-file image: ' + url));
                    };
                    img.src = body;
                } else {
                    callback(new Error('Could not load marker-file image: ' + url));
                }
            });
}
```

The service always return

```
Couldn't get marker-file http://127.0.0.1:4000/images/myimage.png
```

Inside the POD's shell we tried to get CURL

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:4000/images/myimage.png
```

and it works,

also tried to test if node can resolve localhost url with

```
dns.resolve4("127.0.0.1",console.log)
```

and again it works

The service is reachable from outside and if I try to get the image from my external DNS https://my-website.com/images/myimage.png I can see my image, but the API service can't

I also tried, without success, to change the URL from which the service could get the images

- http://127.0.0.1:4000/images/myimage.png,
- https://my-website.com/images/myimage.png

I tried the service locally with minikube and it serve the images whitout any problem.

I would like to understand how to make the service take the images locally inside K8s.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The problem was that the project's dockerfile contained an HTTP_PROXY environment variable with an invalid URL and the request library passes through the Proxy if it is set, removing the HTTP_PROXY variable the calls started working

Comment: @D Spada, Can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: To find the solution we connected to the shell of a POD, then we launched node and first we tried to get the image using the fs library
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/var/www/mysite/images/myimage.png', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data);
});
and we saw that node.js was able to take the image.

Comment: So we've created a simplified version of the original function that uses the request library:
to get image from localhost
At this point the library returned the error "Could not load marker-file image" and scrolling the error in the console we found an a Url section with "http_proxy"

Comment: @D Spada, Please provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLUTION]

To find the solution we connected to the shell of a POD with a Kubernetes IDE (Lens), then we launched node.js with *node* command

1. we tried to get the image using the fs library and we saw that node.js was able to take the image

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/var/www/mysite/images/myimage.png', 'utf8', function (err,data) { 
 if (err) { return console.log(err); } 
 console.log(data); 
});
```

2. So we've created a simplified version of the original function that uses the request library: to get image from localhost

```
var request = require('request')
var img = null;
var requestOpts = {
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/images/myimage.png",
                method: 'GET',
                encoding: null, // if you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null
                gzip: true
             };
request(requestOpts, function (err, response, body) {
    if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
        img = body;
    } else {
        console.log(new Error('Could not load marker-file image: ' + JSON.stringify(url)));
    }
});
```

At this point the library returned the error "Could not load marker-file image" and scrolling the error in the console we found an a Url section with "http_proxy".
This help us to understand that there was some error in the Docker configurations:

```
FROM node:10-slim
...
ENV HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy-aws:8080"
...
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js"]
```